# Environment variables in manifest.json - Chrome Extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, environment-variables, manifest.json

Is it possible to set environment variables in the manifest.json file of a Chrome Extension?

Comment: The final manifest.json can only use [locale variables](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n). If you use webpack or other bundler you can write a hook to process the source manifest.json and resolve the environment variables there.

Comment: Did you figure this out Isabella? I have the same problem and am about to explore wOxxOm's suggestion of using webpack hooks.

Comment: @PaulWatson I used wOxxOm's suggestion

Comment: Thanks Isabella, I also came across the CopyWebpackPlugin method; https://stackoverflow.com/a/60188143/484337

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like wOxxOm said, I used webpack to proccess manifest.json.

In my case, I needed to set version automatically on manifest file.

I added to webpack script:

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: "public/manifest.json", 
            to: "manifest.json",
            transform(content, path) {
                return modify(content)
            }
        }
    ]),
]
```

And the modify function replaces version on file for the parameter:

```
function modify(buffer) {
  var manifest = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
  let argv = process.argv[2];
  if (argv) manifest.version = argv.split("=")[1];
  let manifest_JSON = JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2);
  return manifest_JSON;
}
```

So, I build like "yarn build --version=x.x" and webpack do what I need.

PS: if you're going to use this, remember to change:

- the manifest.json directory, if necessary;
- the value in the modify function, in my case it was version

Answer (score 6):

As the OP has mentioned in [her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739609/7929984), using the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) in the `webpack.config.js` file is the way to go if you're building your Chrome Extension with React. However, if your React app is based on `create-react-app`, directly editing the `webpack.config.js` file (which is located in `node_modules/react-scripts/config`) is [not recommended](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/99#issuecomment-234657710).

In such a case, use [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco), which is an npm package that can be used to customize an app based on `create-react-app`. Here's how you do it:

- Install craco into your project using `npm i @craco/craco`.
- Install `copy-webpack-plugin` as a dev-dependency in your project using `npm i --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin`.
- Let's suppose we're creating a development and a production build of our Chrome Extension. Let's also suppose we've already assigned `"version": "0.1.0"` in our Chrome Extension's `manifest.json`. Depending on the build type, we'd like to assign accordingly the `version_name` field in our Chrome Extension's `manifest.json`, e.g., `"version_name": "0.1.0 dev"` for development and `"version_name": "0.1.0"` for production. In your React app's `package.json`, introduce two fields (the script names can be whatever you wish) as follows:

  ```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build-dev": "CRX_ENV=dev craco build", // or "set CRX_ENV=dev&& craco build" in the case of Windows
    "build-prod": "CRX_ENV=prod craco build", // or "set CRX_ENV=prod&& craco build" in the case of Windows
    ...
  }
  ```
- Create a new file called `craco.config.js` in the root of your project. As per your need, do something similar to the following in the `craco.config.js` file:

  ```
  const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin")

  module.exports = {
    webpack: {
      plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
          patterns: [
            {
              from: "public/manifest.json",
              to: "manifest.json",
              transform(content, path) {
                return modifyManifest(content)
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      ],
    },
  }

  function modifyManifest(buffer) {
    const manifest = JSON.parse(buffer.toString())
    if (process.env.CRX_ENV === "dev") {
      manifest.version_name = `${manifest.version} dev`
    } else if (process.env.CRX_ENV === "prod") {
      manifest.version_name = `${manifest.version}`
    }
    const manifestJson = JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2)
    return manifestJson
  }
  ```
- Run `npm run build-dev`. It will create a folder called `build` in your project root. This `build` folder is your unpacked Chrome Extension, which you can load into Chrome using the "Load unpacked" button on the `chrome://extensions` page. Once loaded, you should be able to see `0.1.0 dev` as the version name of your Chrome Extension.
- Delete the `build` folder created from the previous step and run `npm run build-prod`, and repeat the same steps. You should be able to see `0.1.0` as the version name of your Chrome Extension on the `chrome://extensions` page.