# Different development and build configuration with web-ext

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, web-ext

I am working with a browser extension project and want to have a different URL used in `background.js` during development time and build time. I want to do this without having to remember to change the code between development and build. With a server project I'd simply use dotenv/environment variables but that's not available to extensions which effectively run client side.

In `background.js` I have a `fetch` using this `api_base_url` (we develop the API too);

```
...
const api_base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/'
...
```

Before I build (`web-ext build`) I have to manually that to something like;

```
...
const api_base_url = 'http://a.domain.com/v1/'
...
```

Ideally it would be something like;

```
...
const api_base_url = ENV['API_BASE_URL']
...
```

and I'd have a `.env` in local dev of;

```
API_BASE_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/'
```

and `.env.production` (or `.env.build`) of;

```
API_BASE_URL='http://a.domain.com/v1/'
```

This is also a problem in `manifest.json` where I need to whitelist the different URLs in `permissions` e.g.

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "https://a.domain.com/v1/*",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/*"
  ]
```

This isn't a run-time per-user option so `browser.storage` and `options.js` isn't what we're looking for.

Comment: You need to write your build script yourself, including text replacement tools and web-ext to get the result you want. What operating system are you developing on?

Comment: Thank you, I'm on macOS. I've found a way using webpack and dotenv and will post as an answer soon. I could use bash, simpler, but webpack will become useful to the project as it gets more complex (CSS, bundling etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured this out but the basic answer is to add webpack and use `dotenv-webpack` for entry files like `background.js` and `copy-webpack-plugin` for non-entry files like `manifest.json`. These plugins will replace string occurrences of `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME` with the value from `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME`.

This literally happens and it took me a few tries to understand it.

```js
// .env
API_BASE_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/'

// ./background.js
const api_base_url = process.env.API_BASE_URL

// manifest.json
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "process.env.API_BASE_URL*"
],

// webpack => ./dist/main.js
const api_base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/'

// webpack => ./dist/manifest.json
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/*"
],
```

Here is the webpack config;

```js
// ./webpack.config.js
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const DotenvPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack')
module.exports = (env) => {
  const dotenvPath = __dirname + '/.env.' + env

  const replaceWithProcessEnv = (content) => {
    for (var key in require('dotenv').config({ path: dotenvPath }).parsed) {
      content = content.replace(new RegExp('process.env.' + key, 'g'), process.env[key])
    }
    return content
  }

  return {
    plugins: [
      new DotenvPlugin(
        {
          path: dotenvPath,
          safe: true
        }
      ),
      new CopyPlugin(
        [
          {
            from: 'src/manifest.json',
            transform(content) {
              return replaceWithProcessEnv(content.toString())
            }
          }
        ]
      )
    ]
  }
}
```

I have made a complete working example here;
https://github.com/paulmwatson/web-ext-environments